# Stream order data for Canadian streams

Tags: canada, stream-order, nhd, strahler

I am researching streams and I want to select 1st-3rd order streams in North America. The NHD Plus V2 Flowline Network contains stream order (Strahler) in the packaged data and I was wondering if stream order has been calculated in the same fashion for Canada. I have downloaded the 50k NHN data for each Canadian province, but I have not seen stream order in the data anywhere.
I would like to avoid having to calculate stream orders for the entirety of Canada on my personal PC. Has anyone ever seen a data set like that for Canada?

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: If you do decide to compute it, check out [RivEX](http://www.rivex.co.uk/) for ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

In Ontario, at least, this data is maintained by each (most?) Conservation Authority, each of which is responsible for one major watershed.  For instance, the Rideau Valley Conservation Authority has it at https://gis.rvca.ca/server/rest/services/RVCA_Hydrology_Service/MapServer/0 (layer name RVCA_Streamorder). The adjacent Mississippi Valley Conservation Authority also has it on its ArcGis server endpoint somewhere, as have many others (these are the ones relevant for me).

I am not aware of a Province-wide, much less pan-Canadian, dataset.